# Avoid importing of type when typings available on package?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using a package where it requires `Engine` which is part of the package. Under the `node_modules` it contains a `types` folder with export definitions for the `Engine` class. Is there a way I can add `import { Engine } from "tsparticles-engine"` to my Typescript typings so I don't need to import it on the file where it is being used?

I'm new to using typescript but I thought the reason for a `typings.d.ts` file was to add typings from packages.

```
<style lang="scss">
</style>

<template>

    <Particles id="tsparticles"
               :particlesInit="particlesInit"
               url="/assets/particles.json" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { loadFull } from "tsparticles";
import { Engine } from "tsparticles-engine"; // this line

export default {
    methods: {
        particlesInit: (engine: Engine) => {
            loadFull(engine);
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Types are rarely added to the global scope. What if two packages had a type named `Engine`, how would TypeScript know which one you meant? It is intended that you import the types you refer to by name, just like types in your own files.